# 403 error on Ajax Post Laravel shared hosting

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, hosting, shared

Site works completely OK on other hosting. That is also shared. But doesn't work on current hosting when an Ajax post request is made. The server(not app) responds with 403.

What should I do now? I used postman and it works okay. No problem in url also.

**Update:**
the code for ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.href.split('?')[0],
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        window.location = data.redirect_to;
    },
    error: function(data){
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: "What should I do now?" Post suspicious code with question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was "not setting" content-type in headers.
I changed the code into:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.href.split('?')[0],
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data){
        window.location = data.redirect_to;
    },
    error: function(data){
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
});
```

And it worked.